# How to scrape data of post genereted url in php using curl

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I want a data from other website which url looks like "https://www.example.com/quote/results" after fill all data. I not understand how to pass data to get correct data.I try this code but it show only blank page.

```
    <?php 

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$czip=$_POST['czip'];
$dest=$_POST['dest'];
$weight=$_POST['weight'];

$url = 'https://www.example.com/quote/results';

$data = array('collection-zip' =>$czip,
                  'destination'=>$dest,
                  'weight' =>$weight);
$ch = curl_init();                
$timeout=5;
$ch = curl_init($url);
$data=http_build_query($data);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);             

curl_close($ch);
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($data);
   exit;
   if($headers['http_code'] == 200){ 
      echo $content;
      exit;
   }


?>
```

I am not familiar with curl and web scraping.
if any soultion please share.

Comment: so you need the data on how to pass the data to get the correct return data.  What data are you getting now?

Comment: i am getting  blank page.

Comment: then you should put `ini_set('display_errors', -1);` at the top of the page because you likely have a synax error in there.

Comment: i try this but still getting blank page

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); add this linr and then try